# Value attribute, why required sometimes?

Tags: python

I was playing around with python and cgi and was wondering why there is a difference between the two examples below:

**Example 1** (partial)

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
for field in form.keys():
    sys.stdout("%s ----> %s<br />" % (field, form[field].value))
```

**Example 2**

```
form = {'one': '1', 'two': '2', 'three': '3'}
for field in form.keys():
    sys.stdout("%s ---> %s\n" % (field, form[field]))
```

Why do you need the `.value` attribute in the first example, but in the second example you do not require it to return the key's value?

Comment: possibly because the objects returned by `cgi.FieldStorage.__getitem__` have an attribute `value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the first example.

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
```

form is now an object of the type `FieldStorage` this object can be accessed like a dictionary (`object[key]`) and it will return an object, however, unlike a normal dictionary like in example 2 which contains just strings. the object returned in example 1's dictionary-like access must be told how you want to display it, or access it, in this case, you want the objects `value`.

to better understand this, you could try some on-the-fly debugging.

by iterating over the items in `cgi.FieldStorage()` and then you can see what kind of objects they are. maybe try playing with an individual object and see how it works?

incidently, if the object has a `__str__` function you might not need the `.value` for more information you can read about [classes](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes) and [`__str__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what is stored in the `form` dict.

In the example 1, it is some rather complex object which obviously cannot be transformed into a string in the desired way.

Example 2's dict entries are just strings, so they are fine to be used directly.